# Gtk.TreeView editable columns in Vala

Tags: treeview, gtk, vala

Is there any simple way how to make a Gtk.Treeview updating its columns on edit?

I build the Treeview based on a Gtk.ListStore model. I initialize the cells like this:

```
Gtk.CellRendererText valueCells = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
valueCells.editable = true;
tree_view.insert_column_with_attributes (-1, "Key", valueCells, "text", 0);
tree_view.insert_column_with_attributes (-1, "Value", valueCells, "text", 1);
```

I'm now able to select and edit the columns until I exit the Selection. Neither the TreeView nor the ListStore is updated. Tried several solutions I found written in different languages but nothing worked. I understood i have to update the model, but couldn't figure out how to find the reference to that.. Do I miss something essential? O.o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to connect the `edited` signal to get notified of changes made by the user, here is a complete example:

```
class MainWindow : Gtk.Window {

    public MainWindow () {
        Gtk.TreeView tree_view = new Gtk.TreeView ();
        setup_treeview (tree_view);

        add(tree_view);
    }


    private void setup_treeview (Gtk.TreeView view) {
        var listmodel = new Gtk.ListStore (4, typeof (string), typeof (string),
                                              typeof (string), typeof (string));
        view.set_model (listmodel);

        view.insert_column_with_attributes (-1, "Account Name", new Gtk.CellRendererText (), "text", 0);
        view.insert_column_with_attributes (-1, "Type", new Gtk.CellRendererText (), "text", 1);

        var cell = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
        cell.set ("foreground_set", true);
        cell.editable = true;
        cell.edited.connect ((path, new_text) => {
                stdout.printf (path + "\n");
                stdout.printf (new_text + "\n");
                stdout.flush ();
            });
        view.insert_column_with_attributes (-1, "Balance", cell, "text", 2, "foreground", 3);

        Gtk.TreeIter iter;
        listmodel.append (out iter);
        listmodel.set (iter, 0, "My Visacard", 1, "card", 2, "102,10", 3, "red");

        listmodel.append (out iter);
        listmodel.set (iter, 0, "My Mastercard", 1, "card", 2, "10,20", 3, "red");
    }

}

int main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow ();

    window.title = "Tree View test";
    window.border_width = 10;
    window.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;
    window.set_default_size (350, 200);
    window.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);

    window.show_all ();
    Gtk.main ();
    return 0;
}
```

The important bit is here:

```
var cell = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
cell.editable = true;
cell.edited.connect ((path, new_text) => {
    stdout.printf (path + "\n");
    stdout.printf (new_text + "\n");
    stdout.flush ();
});
```

It will print the path and the new_text of the modified cell to the command line.

All you have to do now is to update the model accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
using Gtk;

public class viewWindow:Gtk.Window {
 public viewWindow() {
 this.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);
 set_default_size(200,150);

 Gtk.ListStore list_store=new Gtk.ListStore(1, typeof(string));
 Gtk.TreeIter iter;

 list_store.append(out iter);
 list_store.set(iter, 0, "Earth");
 list_store.append(out iter);
 list_store.set(iter, 0, "Mars");

 Gtk.TreeView view=new TreeView.with_model(list_store);
 this.add(view);

 Gtk.CellRendererText cell=new Gtk.CellRendererText();
 view.insert_column_with_attributes(-1, "Planet", cell, "text", 0);
 cell.editable = true;

 cell.edited.connect ((path, data) => {
  Gtk.TreePath tPath = new Gtk.TreePath.from_string(path);
  var model = view.get_model();
  var res = model.get_iter(out iter, tPath);
  if (res == true) {
   list_store.set(iter, 0, data);
  }
 });
}

public static int main(string[] args) {
 Gtk.init(ref args);
 var view = new viewWindow();
 view.show_all();
 Gtk.main();
 return 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: Add some word in your solution

Comment: This. The first example gets you as far as the callback being executed, but the printf doesn't do anyone any good.

The key here is how to convert the `path` parameter back to the column & row in the liststore where the data came from so you can write `data` back to it from within the edited callback.